# In facebook apps When i right click on a menu its open outside the canvash?

Tags: facebook

I am working on a Facebook apps when i right click on a menu it open in new tab but outside the canvas what the problem with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the browser and not your application. I use some JavaScript to detect if the user is viewing my app outside of Facebook, and redirect them back to the Facebook Canvas URL. The below code will redirect those that open links in New Tabs / Windows to go back to facebook.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( top === self ) {
    window.top.location = '{$canvas_url}';
}
</script>
```